# Need Help Optimizing Character Array Search Using NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

I need to compare two scored word lists (new and old) to find words on the new list that are not on the old one (ignoring the word scores) and return a Python list of the new words (with the scores). The input lists are formatted as follows:

```
new = ['RED;25','BLUE;30','YELLOW;50','GREEN;10']
old = ['GREEN;50','YELLOW;50','PURPLE;50']
```

And, the output list needs to have the same format. The code I developed using NumPy is:

```
import numpy as np

def find_new_words(new, old):

        n, o = np.char.array(new), np.char.array(old)
        w_n = np.char.array([i[0:i.find(';')] for i in new])
        w_o = np.char.array([i[0:i.find(';')] for i in old])
        ans = [n[np.char.find(i, w_n) == 0] for i in np.setdiff1d(w_n, w_o)]
        lst = [i for sublist in np.array(ans).tolist() for i in sublist]

        return lst
```

which returns the correct answer of:

```
['BLUE;30', 'RED;25']
```

for the sample lists shown above.

The issue I am having is my lists have tens of thousands of entries and this function takes forever to process (around eight minutes for old and new lists of around 50,000 entries each, which is ridiculous). Any thoughts on how I can speed things up? It looks like I'm just doing too many unnecessarily repetitive loops. I'm sure there's a more Pythonic (NumPonic??) way of doing this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `np.char` functions essentially apply python string methods to the elements of the array. Speed is about the same as a list comprehension. `numpy` does not have its own compiled string methods.  It might be better to stick with lists.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting your function to work with lists and not numpy:

```
def find_wlist(new, old):
        w_n = [i[0:i.find(';')] for i in new]
        w_o = [i[0:i.find(';')] for i in old]
        d = set(w_n).difference(set(w_o))
        lst = [x for x,z in zip(new, w_n) if z in d]
        return lst
In [367]: find_wlist(new, old)
Out[367]: ['RED;25', 'BLUE;30']
```

Different order, but same results.

```
In [368]: timeit find_new_words(new, old)
235 µs ± 2.11 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [369]: timeit find_wlist(new, old)
4.61 µs ± 127 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

`numpy` does not offer much, if any, performance advantages when working with strings, especially not matching operations like this.

Comment: you're my hero. I have been trying to do this on my own for a week. Your solution works perfectly and is as fast as greased lightning. Thank you so much for your help!